# how to lookup column that has versioning enabled in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, versioning

I have a custom list "Requests" which is used to capture user requests. There is a column "Comments" which I have enabled versioning to capture conversation exchange between the user and request management officer.

While designing the workflow in SharePoint Designer, I tried to use the lookup tool to return all the comments by using [%Current Item:Comments%] but it returns blank. I figured since versioning is enabled there needs to be some way to target/loop through which comment for it to return but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Environment: Office365 SharePoint Online

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Update1:
Ok after comments from Surya I did some tests. When a SharePoint action was used to update the column, output is successful.

[image]

[image]

---

**But once I removed the SharePoint action, output becomes blank. Is this some kind of bug?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and for me it is returning the most updated value of the comments field. can you please recheck once.

[image: attaching the screenshot of the workflow which i have created]

Comment: I have tried it many times, it always returns blank.

Comment: I added the screen shot of the workflow which i created and it returns me the current version of the comments. Workflow is on the list where the versioning is enabled. on update/add of the item, i am adding an item to some other list with the current value of the "comments" field. Let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: I did some tests and updated my original question. if I used an update action, it does output the latest comment but if I remove the action, output returns to blank even the user has saved some comments.